# How to run npm start via Jenkins to start application

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

executing shell

```
npm start &
```

wont work. Jenkins jobs either runs endless or npm does not start right.

What would be the proper way especially when u need to start multiple nodejs servers.

Is there a way over the jenkins nodejs plugin, via grunt or install a linux service running npm start ?

Answer (score 4):

I also came across the same issue and figured out a way to do it. The command setsid helped me.

`setsid npm start >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &`